# Thread pool for async tasks?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, swt, jface

I'm using JFace to write a simple file-explorer application. The application's logic can be simplified as:

1. Display contents of a folder in a TableViewer.
2. Whenever a folder item gets double-clicked, async-load (to keep UI responsive) its contents and display it.

So in my opnion, there are at least 2 threads get involved: a) the UI thread and b) the background thread that fetches contents of a folder.

What really bothers me here is how does the two threads communicate and do I have to 'invent the wheel'? To be more specific:

1. **How to tell the background thread when an item gets double-clicked?** I suppose I need a task queue shared between the two threads or does JFace already provides some async-task mechanism?
2. **How to tell the UI thread that the data have arrived and repaint the table?** Which one to choose, asyncexec or syncexec?

Answer (score 1):

What I would usually do is something like this:

```
// On double-click, start a new thread
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // Get your new data in this thread
        final MyFancyDataObject data = SomeOtherClass.goAndGetMyData(); 

        // Update the GUI, this is the safe way to do it from a non-gui-thread
        Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                GuiClass.updateContent(data);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but in which thread will this code be run? Is it ok to update UI inside run()?

Comment: @frog Apologies, still a bit tired this morning. Will update the answer (as it is wrong at the moment).

Comment: @frog OK, updated. The new thread gets the data and inside you can safely notify the GUI.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes a lot sense now. But I've been told that start a new thread whenever needed and destroy it when it's done is too costly. Does SWT provide any mechanism so that I can just throw the runnable class to a background thread (managed by SWT) and get it run asyncly?

Comment: @frog Not that I know of. There is if you're developing an Eclipse RCP. If so, [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html) is a resource worth reading.